# Textarea keypress not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyup

My code won't work. It's supposed to alert whenever a user presses a key while focused inside of a textbox element!

```
$("#yourcode").keyup(function() {
        alert("I found Hogwarts.");
});
```

Comment: what's the HTML look like, Harambe Squad

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait until the DOM is ready before adding the *keyup* handler. This can be achieved by calling [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) after using [$()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/) to get a DOM reference to the *document* (i.e. `$(document)`). Also make sure you load jQuery before you load the script:

#### JS:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#yourcode").keyup(function() {
                alert("I found Hogwarts.");
        });
    });
</script>
```

#### HTML:

```
<textarea id="yourcode"></textarea>
```

Here is a working example (also available in [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jeremykenedy/jfw2fro0/)):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#yourcode").keyup(function() {
    alert("I found Hogwarts.");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="yourcode"></textarea>
```